# Discord.py How to get the list of all the audit logs?

Tags: discord.py

I'm searching a way to get all the audit logs printed on a txt file, because I want then the bot to send that txt file to the admin's email. How can I get all the audit logs?

Answer (score 1):

You use `async for ... in guild.audit_logs(limit=100)`
The function has a lot more different parameters, all of which you can find [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.audit_logs).

Here is an example on how to use it:

```py
async def save_audit_logs(guild):
     with open(f'audit_logs_{guild.name}', 'w+') as f:
          async for entry in guild.audit_logs(limit=100):
               f.write('{0.user} did {0.action} to {0.target}'.format(entry))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
     if message.content.startswith('audit'):
         await save_audit_logs(message.channel.guild)
```

Additional info:
This is an async iterator, meaning it can **only be used** in async functions.

Every audit log entry is of [this class](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.AuditLogEntry), I recommend reading up on it a bit.