# Is there any way to retrieve the creator of a channel in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I read through the API of **discord.py**, yet I didn't manage to find a way to fetch the user who created a channel on the **'guild_channel_create'** event. I am trying to make a discord logger, and so far, this is where I have been stuck.

Comment: I don't think you can retrieve the creator of a channel, but you can check who sent the first message or things like this...  Yo can't even check who have created a new channel when the bot is running, because on_guild_channel_create supports only the ***channel*** argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry to say that but neither discord.py or the discord API allows it. You could use the audit logs of the server, referr to this question [Discord.py How to get the list of all the audit logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61027352/discord-py-how-to-get-the-list-of-all-the-audit-logs) for more info of how to do that.