# discord.py get channel creator/author

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Its possible to get the creator/author of a channel? Example code of what I want to achieve:

```
async def on_guild_channel_create(self, channel):
    await channel.edit(topic = f"The author of this channel is: {channel.author}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but atm, there is no way to get the creator of a channel using discord py, but I heard people used audit logs to achieve something similar, so that might be something you could try.

Please check out this question

[Discord.py How to get the list of all the audit logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61027352/discord-py-how-to-get-the-list-of-all-the-audit-logs)